# Change remaining radio buttons in group after changing state of one radio button in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a set of radio button. I have managed state by useState. when the user select one radio button, the other radio buttons should turn false. I am trying a basic if else to deal with this. I feel I am doing it wrong and can be done more efficiently. Is there any other way to do it. Kindly help.

```
  const [trans,setTrans] = useState({
    expense : false, income : false,
    lend : false}
  );
  const setRadio = (event)=>{

    const buttonName = event.target.id;
    if(buttonName==="expense"){
      setTrans((prev) =>({...prev,[buttonName]:true,income:false,lent:false}));
    }
    if(buttonName==="income"){
      setTrans((prev) =>({...prev,[buttonName]:true,expense:false,lent:false}));
    }
    if(buttonName==="lent"){
      setTrans((prev) =>({...prev,[buttonName]:true,income:false,expense:false}));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to populate the state. You can do something like this:

```js
// initialState should be outside your component
let initialState = {
  expense: false,
  income: false,
  lend: false,
};

const [trans, setTrans] = useState({
  ...initialState,
});

const setRadio = (event) => {
  const buttonName = event.target.id;
  let changedTrans = {
    ...initialState,
    [buttonName]: true,
  };
  setTrans(changedTrans);
};
```

Codesandbox link for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/radio-react-jlxhuf